# what control/approach for selection of an integer in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uipickerview

Any recommendations re which approach from a useability perspective for a user to configure one preference for my app, which is number of weeks - probably would make sense to allow it to be anywhere from 2 through to 25 say.  So options which come to mind include:

1. type it in - but would need some validation
2. have a list to pick from (I assume by pushing on another TableView to the UINavigationStack) - but with 25 rows not sure about this (e.g. row 1 = "week 1", row 2 = "week 2" etc)
3. UIPicker wheel - but doesn't sound too good
4. other???

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to us a UIPickerView that shows when you tap to edit